# Delete Item From Dynamic Gridview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a dynamic gridview with data pulled from oracle database.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvData" OnRowDataBound="gvData_RowDataBound" OnPreRender="gvData_PreRender" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvData_SelectedIndexChanged" OnLoad="gvData_Load" OnRowCommand="gvData_RowCommand" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" DataSourceID="DS" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" PageSize="10" ShowFooter="True">
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DS" runat="server">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I am trying to write DELETE/UPDATE statements. I am having a problem with getting values from gridview and adding them to the parameters os SQL statements.

```
protected void gvData_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    DS.DeleteCommand =
            "DELETE FROM TABLE " +
            "WHERE PROBLEM_DEPTH_MD = :PROBLEM_DEPTH_MD";
            "AND API = :API " +
            "AND BUS_AREA_ID = :BUS_AREA_ID";
    DS.DeleteParameters.Add(new Parameter("PROBLEM_DEPTH_MD", TypeCode.String, ??GridViewItemValue??));
}
```

I don't know how to get a value from the gridview. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you need to mention the `DataKeyName` to your gridview of your Primary key Column and then you can access the value of the Selected row of the Gridview like... `e.Keys["DataKeyName"]`

If you want to access a non key field, then it should be like... `e.Values["FieldName"]`

Mention DataKeyName like... `<asp:GridView ID="gvData" DataKeyNames="PrimaryKeyColumn"`

Comment: Where do I set the DataKeyName?

Comment: What if my primary key consists of multiple columns?

Comment: you can mention it in comma seperated :)

Comment: I added DataKeyNames="PROBLEM_DEPTH_MD,API,BUS_AREA_ID" to the gridview and DS.DeleteParameters.Add(new Parameter("PROBLEM_DEPTH_MD", TypeCode.String, e.Keys["PROBLEM_DEPTH_MD"].ToString())); to the code, I get "ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number"

Comment: Whould you mind helping me with the UPDATE statement? Say, I write ""UPDATE table SET field = '73i' WHERE PK1 = :PK1 AND PK2 = :PK2 AND PK3= :PK3". In the end I get an error "ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number". Do you know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the DataKeyNames for you GridView.

You can then use the GridViewDeleteEventArgs to get the Keys property. This will be a dictionary of Key/Value pairs which correspond to the DataKeyFields which you set. In essence it allows you to get your primary keys-- which is what you need to delete.

assuming primary keys are PROBLEM_DEPTH_MD, API, AND BUS_ARE_ID, you would set the DataKeyNames to be "PROBLEM_DEPTH_MD,API,AND BUS_ARE_ID".

You could then grab these keys in your delete event with e.Keys. If you loop over them you should be able to get the values to add  your parameters.

Here is some more information on this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx

Comment: Okay, I am a bit confused here. I got it worknig with adding single column to the DataKeyNames. When I add two more columns there, how do I add all of those parameters to the DELETE statment?

Comment: I think the way you were doing i in your comment above-- but is there an issue with your sql statement "WHERE PROBLEM_DEPTH_MD = :PROBLEM_DEPTH_MD"-- should that have a space?

Comment: I am accepting Muhammad Akhtar's answer; he answered 2 mins earlier. Sorry :( But thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: no problem at all-- i read his comments too- they were pretty helpful.

Comment: Whould you mind helping me with the UPDATE statement? Say, I write ""UPDATE table SET field = '73i' WHERE PK1 = :PK1 AND PK2 = :PK2 AND PK3= :PK3". In the end I get an error "ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number". Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: Do you have any ideas? I described it more here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6668162/791952